# What is the Time Complexity, Space complexity and Algorithm for strstr() function in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, string-search

I was curious about the cost of using the default, old fashioned strstr() function in C++. What is its Time and Space complexity? Which algorithm does it use? 
We have other algorithms with below Worst Case Time and Space complexity :
Let n = length of string, m = length of pattern

1. Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm : Time = O(n+m), Space = O(m)
2. Rabin-Karp Algorithm         : Time = O(n*m), Space = O(p) (p = p patterns of combined length m)
3. Boyer-Moore Algorithm        : Time = O(n*m), Space = O(S) (S = size of character set)
   In any way strstr() is better than above mentioned algorithms, in terms of Time and Space complexities?

Comment: Basically, it's not specified. Not a very satisfactory answer, I know. Do you have a specific implementation you want to know about?

Comment: I meant a specific implementation of the function, or C standard library. For instance, the one in Gnu libc, or the one used by MS Visual Studio, or some other one?

Comment: Sorry.. I dont have any BoB..

Comment: glibc is using KMP, see [strstr.c source file](https://github.com/jeremie-koenig/glibc/blob/master-beware-rebase/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strstr.c), although it is modified with some sse2 optimizations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the C standard it just says, in §7.24.5.7:

> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
>  #include <string.h>
>  char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> The strstr function locates the first occurrence in the string pointed to by s1 of the sequence of characters (excluding the
>   terminating null character) in the string pointed to by s2.
>
> #### Returns
>
> The strstr function returns a pointer to the located string, or a null pointer if the string is not found. If s2 points to
>   a string with zero length, the function returns s1.

So the complexity is unspecified. As far as I can tell, an implementation is allowed to use any of those algorithms.